# Convert multiple nested JSON to CSV in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON and I want to Convert it into CSV but the problem is that the json is multiple nested and the inner fields does not always has the same number of objects.

For E.g.

Kit 1 has 5 Products and Kit 2 has 3 products (along with the quantity of products in both cases)

KIT 1:

```
"kit":{
               "products":[
                  {
                     "product":"PP001",
                     "quantity":1
                  },
                  {
                     "product":"PS001",
                     "quantity":1
                  },
                  {
                     "product":"PL001",
                     "quantity":1
                  },
                  {
                     "product":"FIN1187",
                     "quantity":3
                  },
                  {
                     "product":"FSS001",
                     "quantity":4
                  }
               ],
               "kit_client":"Lumax Mannoh Allied Technologies Limited",
               "kit_name":"KIT1187",
               "kit_info":"Gear Lever TACO_FLC",
               "components_per_kit":66
            },
```

KIT 2:

```
"kit":{
               "products":[
                  {
                     "product":"CRT6423",
                     "quantity":1
                  },
                  {
                     "product":"CIN1198A",
                     "quantity":2
                  },
                  {
                     "product":"CSS001",
                     "quantity":3
                  }
               ],
               "kit_client":"Lumax Mannoh Allied Technologies Limited",
               "kit_name":"KIT1198B",
               "kit_info":"Floor Sealing Assy_Crate",
               "components_per_kit":72
            },
            "flow":"LMXMNH_Manesar_Nashik_Floor Sealing Assy W501",
            "asked_quantity":3,
            "alloted_quantity":3
```

I tried `json_normalize` but it flattens the outer dict.
I want the output to look something like this:

```
transaction_no  dispatch_date send_from_warehouse  sales_order  flow_name  kit_name  asked_quantity  alloted_quantity  product1  product1 quantity  product2  product2 quantity...( to the maximum product in all JSON)
```

The complete JSON:

https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cbd770f5

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: @Roy2012 The expected output(in the question) are columns of CSV

Comment: Please attach your current code

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski currently I am normalizing data `pd.json_normalize(data)` and then convert it to CSV by `data.to_csv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_normalize` is a nice tools for simple things. When you have a deeply nested json, it is better to process it *by hand* with a recursive custom function.

Here you want to keep all the keys that have immediate data, except for products that should be numbered.

A possible way is to build a set to keep the field names, and recursively build a list of dict for the data.

```
data = json.loads(js)

def find_keys(data, keys=None, lst= None, cur = None):
    if keys is None:
        keys = set()      # will contain the field names
        lst = []          # list of dict for the data
        cur = {}          # current data row
    if isinstance(data, list):
        for sub in data:
            cur = cur.copy()      # create a new row for each item in of a list
            lst.append(cur)
            find_keys(sub, keys, lst, cur)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        for k,v in data.items():
            if k == 'products':   # special processing for products
                for i,p in enumerate(v, 1):
                    for (k1, v1) in p.items():
                        keys.add(k1 + str(i))
                        cur[k1 + str(i)] = v1
            elif isinstance(v, (list, dict)):
                cur = cur.copy()   # a new row for each nested json
                lst.append(cur)
                find_keys(v, keys, lst, cur)
            else:
                keys.add(k) # a plain data (number or string): feed the row
                cur[k] = v
    return lst, keys

lst, keys = find_keys(data)

# sort the products to come after the other keys
fieldnames = sorted(keys, key=lambda k: 1 * 2*int(k[8:])
                    if k.startswith('quantity')
                    else 2*int(k[7:]) if k.startswith('product') else 0)

# and use the csv module here
with open('data.csv', newline='') as fd:
    wr = csv.DictWriter(fd, fieldnames)
    _ = wr.writeheader()
    wr.writerows(lst)
    print(fd.getvalue())

# or build a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=fieldnames)
```

---

If you only want a subset of columns, you could use `reindex`:

```
columns = ['asked_quantity', 'freight_charges', 'driver_name', 'sales_order', 
           'id', 'transport_by', 'alloted_quantity', 'is_delivered', 'kit_info', 
           'dispatch_date', 'expected_delivery', 'vehicle_number', 'vehicle_type',
           'remarks', 'kit_name', 'lr_number', 'owner', 'transaction_no', 'kit_client', 
           'driver_number', 'send_from_warehouse', 'flow', 'model', 'components_per_kit',
           'product1', 'quantity1', 'quantity2', 'product2',
           'quantity3', 'product3', 'quantity4', 'product4', 'quantity5', 'product5',
           'product6', 'quantity6'
          ]

df = df.reindex(columns=columns)
```

Comment: what is `js` in `json.loads(js)`?

Comment: As you said that you had a json object, I assumed that you had a string. `js` is that string. If the json object is in a file, use `data = json.load(open('file.json'))`

Comment: I updated the code further but stuck at replicating some columns in the dataframe such that it looks like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EaZqnA51gzB97IJIIuG9DVwnSYkMCLGM/view?usp=sharing
Here's the updated code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cy2DId8a0n0HC984gjji5oenZhyDOyLD/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The 'classic' way to extract data from such a json is as follows:

```
d = json.load(open("my_file.json"))
df = pd.json_normalize(d, record_path=["flows", "kit", "products"], 
                  meta=["transaction_no", "dispatch_date", "send_from_warehouse", "sales_order", 
                        ["flows", "flow"], 
                        ["flows", "kit", "kit_name"], 
                        ["flows", "asked_quantity"], 
                        ["flows", "alloted_quantity"]
                       ])
```

The output is as follows:

```
    product quantity    transaction_no  dispatch_date   send_from_warehouse sales_order flows.flow  flows.kit.kit_name  flows.asked_quantity    flows.alloted_quantity
0   PP001   1   2324    2020-08-11T04:40:34.876000Z Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  105 LMXMNH_Manesar_Nashik_Transmission Gear Leaver...   KIT1162A    3   3
1   PS001   1   2324    2020-08-11T04:40:34.876000Z Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  105 LMXMNH_Manesar_Nashik_Transmission Gear Leaver...   KIT1162A    3   3
2   PL001   1   2324    2020-08-11T04:40:34.876000Z Yantraksh Logistics Private limited_GGNPC1  105 LMXMNH_Manesar_Nashik_Transmission Gear Leaver...   KIT1162A    3   3
```

Does that answer your question? To create a column for the first product, a column for the second product, etc., you can do some pivoting.

Comment: I am getting `has non iterable value 2324 for path transaction_no. Must be iterable or null.` as error

Comment: What data are you using? I'm using the json file downloaded from the link in the question, and it's working fine.

Comment: I am using the same data and also tried this `pd.json_normalize(d, record_path=["flows", "kit", "products"], meta=["transaction_no", "dispatch_date", "send_from_warehouse", "sales_order" ])` and still the same error

Comment: what version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I am using version '1.0.1`

Comment: I'm using 1.0.5, but I somehow doubt if that's what's causing the issue. Are you certain you're using the data from https://jsonblob.com/849d14e4-dec2-11ea-a672-7becf26e7825, as-is?

Comment: I have updated the link, I hope that would be easy to use and when I ran the same code on this file it says: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219865/discussion-between-roy2012-and-rahul-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty simple approach to your JSON

1. `json_normalize()` to get first pass of records (each piece of *kit*)
2. `explode()` the *products*
3. turn it back into JSON `to_dict(orient="records")`
4. `json_normalize()` it again to expand dictionaries in *product*

```
kit = [{'kit': {'products': [{'product': 'PP001', 'quantity': 1},
   {'product': 'PS001', 'quantity': 1},
   {'product': 'PL001', 'quantity': 1},
   {'product': 'FIN1187', 'quantity': 3},
   {'product': 'FSS001', 'quantity': 4}],
  'kit_client': 'Lumax Mannoh Allied Technologies Limited',
  'kit_name': 'KIT1187',
  'kit_info': 'Gear Lever TACO_FLC',
  'components_per_kit': 66}},
{'kit': {'products': [{'product': 'CRT6423', 'quantity': 1},
   {'product': 'CIN1198A', 'quantity': 2},
   {'product': 'CSS001', 'quantity': 3}],
  'kit_client': 'Lumax Mannoh Allied Technologies Limited',
  'kit_name': 'KIT1198B',
  'kit_info': 'Floor Sealing Assy_Crate',
  'components_per_kit': 72},
 'flow': 'LMXMNH_Manesar_Nashik_Floor Sealing Assy W501',
 'asked_quantity': 3,
 'alloted_quantity': 3}]

df = pd.json_normalize(pd.json_normalize(kit)\
            .explode("kit.products").to_dict(orient="records"))

print(df.loc[[0,1,6,7]].to_string(index=False))
```

**sample output**

```
                           kit.kit_client kit.kit_name              kit.kit_info  kit.components_per_kit                                           flow  asked_quantity  alloted_quantity kit.products.product  kit.products.quantity
 Lumax Mannoh Allied Technologies Limited      KIT1187       Gear Lever TACO_FLC                      66                                            NaN             NaN               NaN                PP001                      1
 Lumax Mannoh Allied Technologies Limited      KIT1187       Gear Lever TACO_FLC                      66                                            NaN             NaN               NaN                PS001                      1
 Lumax Mannoh Allied Technologies Limited     KIT1198B  Floor Sealing Assy_Crate                      72  LMXMNH_Manesar_Nashik_Floor Sealing Assy W501             3.0               3.0             CIN1198A                      2
 Lumax Mannoh Allied Technologies Limited     KIT1198B  Floor Sealing Assy_Crate                      72  LMXMNH_Manesar_Nashik_Floor Sealing Assy W501             3.0               3.0               CSS001                      3
```

#### supplementary update

JSON on external link is three levels deep.  Exactly same pattern and you have dataframe.

```
(pd.json_normalize(pd.json_normalize(pd.json_normalize(kit)
                   .explode("flows")
                   .to_dict(orient="records"))
 .explode("flows.kit.products")
 .to_dict(orient="records"))
)
```

Comment: `kit` was just an example to show that kits can have multiple quantities of products.. The actual data is in the link and `Kit` is juts a part of it

Comment: @RahulSharma updated.   That external link is very painful to use,  no download function.  The approach fully works,  systematically break it down.

Comment: if you have saved to cwd the JSON that's on that strange website... `with open("kit.json") as f: kit = json.load(f)` before sample code and it will work